# MMDrawer Swift 2 Redirect to MMDrawer How to set on Click

Tags: swift, mmdrawercontroller

I want to redirect login view controller to mmdrawer controller in swift 
if I am making only mmdrawer it works well because the code is under Appdelegate is working perfect . 
 var window: UIWindow?
    var centerContainer: MMDrawerController?

```
func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool {
    // Override point for customization after application launch.

    _ = self.window!.rootViewController


    let mainStoryboard: UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)

//    let centerViewController  = mainStoryboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("LoginPageViewController") as! LoginView
    //var rootViewController = centerViewController

    let centerViewController = mainStoryboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("CenterController") as! ViewController

    let leftViewController = mainStoryboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("LeftSideViewController") as! LeftSideDrawer



    let leftSideNav = UINavigationController(rootViewController: leftViewController)
    let centerNav = UINavigationController(rootViewController: centerViewController)


    centerContainer = MMDrawerController(centerViewController: centerNav, leftDrawerViewController: leftSideNav)

    centerContainer!.openDrawerGestureModeMask = MMOpenDrawerGestureMode.PanningCenterView;
    centerContainer!.closeDrawerGestureModeMask = MMCloseDrawerGestureMode.PanningCenterView;

    window!.rootViewController = centerContainer
    window!.makeKeyAndVisible()

    return true
```

but my question is how to add login view controller so can redirect it to mmdrawer on sucess . 
Thanks

Comment: You should be able to use login view as per this tutorial. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Ovb7M4EHMWo